# NameError for Pyspark model

Tags: python, pyspark, aggregate-functions, nameerror

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max as max_

DL=merged[merged['method']=='D/L']
sum1=DL.groupBy(['match_id','bowler']).agg(max_('is_wicket'))

window = Window.partitionBy('match_id').orderBy(col(agg(max_('is_wicket'))).desc())
res_4=sum1.withColumn('rank',rank().over(window))
res_4.filter(res_4.rank==1).show()
```

In this code, I am getting `NameError: name 'agg' is not defined.`

Comment: Well, where do you think it is defined? Seems like you're missing `from pyspark.sql.functions import agg`??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you have not imported agg from pyspark.sql.functions.

A better approach would be to rename column and then use it.

```
sum1=DL.groupBy(['match_id','bowler']).agg(max_('is_wicket').alias('max_is_wicket'))

window = Window.partitionBy('match_id').orderBy(col('max_is_wicket').desc())
res_4=sum1.withColumn('rank',rank().over(window))
res_4.filter(res_4.rank==1).show()
```